# Clone a SCSI drive to an IDE drive?

Tags: hard-drive, clone, disk-image, pata, scsi

Is it even possible to clone a SCSI hard drive to an IDE hard drive?  If so what are some good free tools to do so?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done. The question is, will the result be bootable? Redoing the boot loader installation will probably be required.

I have gone in the other direction, from IDE to SCSI with G4L. [G4L](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/) has worked well for me.

Comment: This is possible, I know you can just use the unix `dd` to copy say `sd0` to `hd1` (where `hd0` is the copying computer that you don't want to mess up)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible to clone a SCSI hard drive to an IDE hard drive?

Yes, this is trivial. It is not different from copying PATA to PATA, PATA to SATA, SATA to SATA, SAS to SATA, SAS to SCSi or any other combination.

> If so what are some good free tools to do so?

`dd` is the classic example, though I guess `cat` and `cp` will also work.

Then there are all the nice tools with graphical shells and smart tricks, sunch as Acronis and ghost.

- If this is just a data drive then you are all set with tons of choices.
- If you also want to boot from the drive then you probably want to rewrite /etc/fstab to point to the new disk locations.
- If this is windows and you want to boot from it then it gets much harder. Sysprep might be your best friend.